# Enlace roto: Cómo formular una pregunta

Tags: bug, estado-completado

Saludos hermanos, espero se encuentren bien, acabo de encontrar un bug:

1. Ir a https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
2. Dar click en **cómo pedir ayuda »**
3. Saludar al Error 404.

El error que lanza es porque la URL apunta a:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask-beta

y debería ser https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Gracias por crearme una pregunta solo para mí :$. Ahora en serio, ¡bien visto!

Comment: hahahahahahahahaaaaaaaaa xD!!!! ay mis tripas xD!!!! hahahahahahaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa esto ya fue demasiado #epic hahahahahahaaaa

Comment: Creo que es un error bastante grave, tomando en cuenta que así todos consejos de informarse antes de preguntar resultan en la punta del cerro. UP!

Comment: Aprovecho para agregar: ¿No debería ser "*¿Cómo preguntar?*" en vez de "*cómo pedir ayuda*"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto se ha corregido. ¡Gracias por compartir estos enlaces rotos!

Answer (score 4):

Disculpa para hacer ruido aquí, pero este problema es bastante grave. Como podemos esperar que los usuarios siguen reglas y mejores practicas, si les hacemos imposibles (o extremadamente difícil) de encontrarlos?